# Transparently redirect http://my-domain-name.com to https://my-domain-name.com/web

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website with my front controller in a subdirectory. Then I would like to transparently redirect root folder of the site to subdirectory. Moreover, I have SSL enabled and want to force it for the site.

I succeeded in transparently redirecting root folder to subdirectory by doing this in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So I decided to add https to the `RewriteRule` like this : `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-domain-name.com/web/$1 [QSA,L]`. But I don't get what I want. In fact, I get https forcing but the transparent root folder to subdirectory redirection does not work anymore. I got in my address bar : `https://my-domain-name.com/web` though my wish is to have `https://my-domain-name.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your added rule is implicitly treated like a **redirect**.  Just put it prior to the rule that does the web/ **rewrite**.  This allows you to change the protocol first then continue with your internal rewriting after the request returns on https.

edit: More detail on HTTPS redirect: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: You need to make sure it only runs when it's HTTP, and perhaps add the L flag.  See https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS